# SElinux in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, security, selinux

Has anyone installed SW Linux in Ubuntu? what were your results? does it come with all the same default rules that the Redhat installation does? I like the security of SE linux, but I have a distribution preference to Ubuntu.

Comment: "I like the security of SE linux" -- spoken like someone who hasn't had the exquisite pleasure of spending several hours tweaking each application that runs on the machine, along with regular support calls forever thereafter because the initial policy didn't handle some rare corner case.  IMO, SELinux isn't worth it unless you're the NSA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELinux isn't well integrated with Ubuntu. You can install it, but there's very little in the way of documentation.

Instead, I'd recommend you look at [AppArmor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor), which Ubuntu installs by default and has a lot of support in regular Ubuntu packages. It functions differently than SELinux, but it's a lot easier to understand and configure, and may provide some of the extra security you're after.